# How to store the timestamp in the server side for Cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra

I've tried using the code below:

```
    final Session session = connection.getSession();
    final String keyspaceName = session.getLoggedKeyspace();
    psInsert = session.prepare(QueryBuilder
            .insertInto(keyspaceName, CampaignConstants.TABLE_NAME_SAMPLE)
            .value("ID", QueryBuilder.bindMarker())
            .value("NAME", QueryBuilder.bindMarker())
            .value("UPDATE_TIME", QueryBuilder.now()));
```

The column "UPDATE_TIME" is of type "timestamp". I can't modify it to "TimeUUID" type.

I'm getting this error:

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Type error:
> cannot assign result of function system.now (type timeuuid) to
> update_time (type timestamp)

The function call QueryBuilder.now() returns a Java instance of class: com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Utils$FCall.

I've searched around, but the documentation doesn't specify how to use this now() function using the driver.

Comment: FWIW I think you meant `UPDATE_TIME` instead of `UPDATE_NAME`. Cheers!

Comment: Fixed the typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in CQL you need to use following expression: `toTimestamp(now())`.

For Java driver 4.x it's translated into the following: instead of `QueryBuilder.now()`, you need to use `QueryBuilder.toTimestamp(QueryBuilder.now()`.

For Java driver 3.x, you need to wrap `QueryBuilder.now()` into the [QueryBuilder.fcall](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.8/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/QueryBuilder.html#fcall-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), something like this: `QueryBuilder.fcall("toTimestamp", QueryBuilder.now())`

Comment: It doesn't have the toTimestamp method. I'm using Cassandra driver v3.7.2 here. Do you know any alternative to toTimestamp method?
I have checked the javadoc but there isn't a clear example there:
https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/3.7.2/index.html

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.